# Show mouse position after click (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, position, mouse

I search how to create an application which show the cursor position after click. I find how to reports the current mouse position, but I do not know how show tis in my windows!

I want simply click on a position and show this position on windows label

on Xcode documentation I find `- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent` But i dont know how use this!

Answer (score 1):

`Subclass your NSWindow and then override the mouseDown Event Method`

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    //get the point position where the mouse was clicked on the NSWindow !
    NSPoint event_location = [theEvent locationInWindow];
    NSLog(@"Clicked %f %f",event_location.x,event_location.y);
    // use event_location.x and event.location.y to show the position whereever you like
}
```